# Avoid using node_modules from referenced project in CRA

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I have a mono repo that contains multiple TS CRA projects under different folders.

1. The project #1 is React-Redux app and `shared/` reusable files. This project has its own `node_modules`.
2. The project #2 is another React-Redux project which is referencing #1 to reuse `shared/` files.

Problem:

Whenever I import `.ts` file from #1 to #2 I see that react/redux libraries are used from #1. This cause an error:

```
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Is that possible to force CRA using a single `node_modules` folder for its own components and referenced?

Comment: I dont see how that would be possible...the issue is less about CRA and more about how node imports work.  You're importing file 1 into file 2, and file 1 imports react from its own set of modules.  CRA is designed to be a self contained dev environment for an application, so importing between CRAs is not great practice.  Unless you were to build the project containing file 1 into a node module itself, and list react as a peer dependency in the package.json.  May I ask what you are trying to accomplish with this architecture?

Comment: I understand your concern, but this referencing approach can not be changed... I'm building project #1 with `tsc --build` which does not link modules but has imports. I expected to import appropriate modules from the active project